# open outlook client with attachment

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

I want to open outlook client with files attached to it.

The requirement is that i want to remove some properties of the document and after properties are removed want to attach this files to outlook client.

Can anyone suggest me how to achieve this using C#.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you,
you want to open a new email, whcih could be send by the user?
I implemented this one, and it looked like this code:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/165548/C-Code-snippet-to-send-an-Email-with-attachment-fr

Comment: My requirement is that i want to open outlook at client machine...so that user can enter the recepients mail. I read somewhere that it will open Outlook instance on server... can you please throw some more light on this.. Thanks

Comment: Ah, what technology do you use to communicate with the client machine?
If it's a webserver, it is impossible due to technical restrictions.

Comment: Actually we are using SharePoint 2010 and we want to send documents in document library by opening outlook and attaching documents to it..

Comment: May that is possible - I not really familiar with Sharepoint. I would recommend that you close this question and open a new one, which mentions Sharepoint and the exact circumstances.

Comment: yes, i think will raise this question in SharePoint.Stackexchange...n yes Thanks for the help :)